# Chrome Developer Tools hung at "Loading profile..." prompt while recording runtime performance

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome Developer Tools under Windows 7 to [record runtime performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/#record) (Chrome 67.0.3396.62 (64-bit)).  I am able to click DevTools' Record button to start capturing performance metrics, but when I click its Stop button, the following ***Loading profile...*** prompt appears and never changes:

[image: Status: Loading profile...]

I tried exiting and reloading Chrome, but this problem persists across restarts.  How do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this maybe? Still happens in newer versions, like  99.0.4844.82

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that just exiting and reloading Chrome may not stop all of Chrome's background processes.  For example, here is a screenshot of [Windows Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explore) showing multiple instances of *chrome.exe* still present after I exited Chrome:

[image: Process Explorer showing multiple instances of chrome.exe]

Once I manually killed each of these processes (by clicking on the process and then pressing my Delete key), Chrome Developer Tools' [record runtime performance](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/#record) capability was restored.